# Why does PIX crash while creating render target views in my D3D11 application?

Tags: directx11, slimdx, pix

I'm trying to use PIX to debug my Direct3D11 application. PIX crashes and gives the following stack trace:

```
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x054338e0>IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x00B3E0F0)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x054338e0> IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x00B3E0F0)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x05433978>ID3D10Texture2D::Map(11788512, Unknown D3D10_MAP, 1843764804, 0x00B3EA08)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <E_INVALIDARG><this=0x05433978> ID3D10Texture2D::Map(11788512, Unknown D3D10_MAP, 1843764804, 0x00B3EA08)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x054b70d0>ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x05433978, NULL, 0x00B3E0F4)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <E_INVALIDARG><this=0x054b70d0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x05433978, NULL, 0x00B3E0F4)
```

What can I do to get around this problem so that I can debug my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIX for Windows tool in the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) is not compatible with the DirectX 11.1 or later runtime. This means it will crash if you attempt to debug a Direct3D 11 application on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, or Windows 7 SP1 with KB 2670838 installed with this old tool. Direct3D 9 debugging will work on Windows 7, but that's about it.

Take a look at Visual Studio's Graphics Diagnostics or one of the profiling tools from one of the GPU vendors.

See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/13/directx-11-1-and-windows-7/) and [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/)